# Makefile 1 equals not 1

Tags: makefile

I'm developing a simple makefile but I run into following problem I can't get my head around:

I execute a command and store 1 or 0 in a variable, depending if it succeeds or not.

```
    $(eval EXISTS=$(shell command_to_exec && echo 1 || echo 0))
```

after that I try to check the value like

```
ifeq ($(EXISTS), 1)
  @echo 'equal'
else
  @echo 'not equal'
endif
```

I always get the output `not equal`.

I also tried to compare to another variable, like

```
...
TRUE := 1
...
ifeq ($(EXISTS), $(TRUE))
...
```

but still I get `not equal`

Can somebody explain this to me?

Comment: Is it possible that `command_to_exec` has some output on its own? Can you add a `$(info [$(EXISTS)])` after setting `EXISTS` to see what it looks like?

Comment: I can't repro, but I had to guess in what context your `ifeq` was executed. Demo: https://ideone.com/MruzVG

Comment: Did you check the value of `EXISTS` with, for instance, `$(info X$(EXISTS)X)`? And why do you use `eval`, by the way? Why not simply `EXISTS = $(shell...)`?

Comment: @jacksbox does the solution I provided  works for you?

Comment: The problem isn't the space character in `ifeq`.  The _general_ rule for make is that whitespace _before_ a word is ignored and whitespace _after_ a word is kept.  Unfortunately there are places where this isn't obeyed.  But if you use `ifeq (1, 1)` you'll see it works.  The problem, as alluded to above, is that this is almost certainly being done in a recipe so it can't work.  It's almost impossible for us to help debug makefile issues if we only see a tiny part of the file.  For us to help you need to provide a small, complete example.

Comment: @MadScientist But this rule only applies to literal spaces, right? If the variable contents transports a space as first characters (no matter how it got there) then the compare will fail, though in the programmers mental expansion (but not `make`s) the expression would read `ifeq ( 1, 1)`

Comment: @MadScientist I just testet with  `ifeq ( $(EXISTS), 1)` which also fails. So spaces in front of variable references aren't skipped either.

Comment: I said above, "unfortunately there are places where this isn't obeyed".  You just ran into one: the first argument in an ifeq is one such place.  However, there's no way that the `EXISTS` variable contains spaces at the beginning, given the code we see here, because all spaces after the `=` and before a word _IS_ skipped during variable assignment.  So, `X=y`, `X= y`, and `X=      y` all give `X` the value `y` with no leading spaces.  It's actually a bit tricky to get a variable to contain a value that starts with space.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below code which will give you correct output:
If you are **not** executing inside a make target:

```
$(eval EXISTS=$(shell <your command> && echo 1 || echo 0))
ifeq ($(strip $(EXISTS)),1)
   $(info "equal")
else
   $(info "not equal")
endif
```

and if you are executing inside a make target then see below code:

```
build:
    @echo $(EXISTS)
    @if [ $(EXISTS) -eq 1 ]; then\
        echo "equal";\
    else \
        echo "not equal";\
    fi
```